# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.compat' / Keras compability issue?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have Python 3.11.3 (Windows) installed and use tensorflow and keras (both version 2.12.0). I keep getting the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.compat'

There is a lot of discussion about the error but I could not find a proper solution so far.

The error occurs at the first import from Keras:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
```

The traceback is:

```
  File "C:\Python3\Lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from keras import models
  File "C:\Python3\Lib\site-packages\keras\models\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>  
    from keras.engine.functional import Functional
  File "C:\Python3\Lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 24, in <module>
    import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.compat'
```

When I dig into the Keras files where the error occurs I see that the problem occurs in `functional.py` where `import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf` is called.

When I look into the tensorflow installation, I see that there is a folder

```
...\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat
```

I can import

```
import tensorflow._api.v2 as tf
```

but what will not work is

```
import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
```

I suppose this is a compability issue from Keras. Has anyone solved this problem so far? I think replacing the import might be a solution. However, I would prefer not to mess around in the Keras installation. What are my options here?

Comment: You should import from `tensorflow.keras`.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem, at least not for me.

Comment: Changing the import does not help. Seems to be a compatibility issue. In the end I downgraded Tensorflow and Keras.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try again because when I tried replicating the same code in the given configuration which does not show any error.
Please check the same below.[image]